# how to reset to plus symbol in accordion menu

Tags: jquery

i made an accordion menu with the following JS

```
$(function(){
 $('#accordion .fullChild>a.opener').text('+').addClass('box');

  $('#accordion .opener').click(function() {
  if($(this).text() == "-") {

  $(this).text("+");
  }
  else {

  $(this).text("-");
  }
});
});


            function initMenus() {
    $('ul#accordion ul').hide();

    $('ul#accordion li a.opener').click(
        function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
                if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');

                    return false;
                }
                if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                    if($('#' + parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                        $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');

                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

it all works like i want it to but for one thing. when you toggle one plus open it turns to minus but unless you toggle it again it stays to minus

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZpXrW/1/

the html and css is bare, i would like to learn how i did the scripting wrong and how to make it better--i am assuming there is a much more concise way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to change back to the plus sign, you need to ... change it back, it wont happen on its own. I updated the fiddle using accordion logic to fix the issue http://jsfiddle.net/ZpXrW/2/

Comment: the problem with this is that it also adds the plus sign to the submenu items, i will play with it more

Comment: $('#accordion .fullChild>a.opener').text("+"); works well thanks

Comment: Okay, but why are there opener on the submenu items? are they goning to be accordions too?

Comment: no, its that i dont have a lot of control of the cms without ALOT of hacking. so i put that in in the best place i could. but the query returns more than i wanted.. long story..